# Is a question on campaign contributions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I visited the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help), and reviewed [on-topic](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) subject matters. My apologies, but I am still not clear about the subject of campaign contributions.

I would like to determine three items:

1. Who did Anthem Inc make their contributions to?
2. Who/what contributed to Governor Larry Hogan's campaign?
3. How to uncover indirection, like Anthem Inc paying an intermediate to make a donation?

Searching reveals some superficial data, like contributions to Hogan by sector; but it lacks the granularity needed for a citation. I'm hoping someone more experienced with the subject matter can show me how to find the information.

So my question for Meta is, are questions like the three above on-topic for Politics Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 2):

Questions about campaign contributions in general are on-topic. Your #3 is a good example of a question that's both ontopic and good.

Questions about specific contributions (from or to specific entity, like your examples #1 and #2) are technically on-topic but really really bad questions:

1. They are too localized and likely won't help **anyone** else
2. They are either trivially researched (making them bad quality) or vice versa, impossible to research as the data isn't public (meaning they aren't answerable, in principle, e.g. for super-PAC donations).
3. This one is iffy but I feel that many of them are likely to not be asked in good faith, and mainly are an effort to slander an entity being asked about (either implying that the recipient is bad due to being donated to by unsavory entity; or implying bribery/corruption).

Comment: Ack, thanks, I won't ask. The three questions are related to Anthem's data breach. My comments to the court on the proposed settlement needs citable material. It was not being asked to rant. Thanks again.